# Object has no materials on it but still displays there to be a material

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I'm quite new to Blender so sorry if this is an obvious question, but this cylinder has no materials added to it but still shows as if it has this metal material and I'm not sure why.
[image]

Here is the Blender file if you need it:
https://pasteall.org/blend/9993cea4b1df4396be8ceb93fbd7f823

Comment: It shows it has a material on my end.

Comment: that's weird because if I select it I can see 2 materials in the material list and the one that is assigned to the object is called "can"

Comment: Yeah, same here.

Comment: same here, i see two materials

Comment: Sorry, I think I uploaded the old file, this is the new one which shouldn't have any materials applied to it.
https://pasteall.org/blend/9993cea4b1df4396be8ceb93fbd7f823

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 materials associated with the object, however why their material slots don't appear by default in the material menu is because the material is being added through *Geometry Nodes*. If you want to simply see the material, select the "Can" material from the menu (underlined in red). Also, your Noise Texture should be connected through the *Height* input of the Bump Node (not the *normal* input - also highlighted in red).

[image: Can]

If you want to remove the material, however, you must first make sure there are no assigned material slots in the material menu (your file "came this way" - use the minus button if you added any slots). Visit the Geometry Nodes section, and disconnect the *Set Material* node(s) from the chain:

[image: Chain]