# Object has no material on it but still displays there to be a material

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders

I did ask this question before, however, I accidentally put the old Blender file instead of the new one, sorry.

I'm quite new to Blender so sorry if this is an obvious question, but this cylinder has no materials added to it but still shows as if it has this metal material and I'm not sure why.

Blender file:
https://pasteall.org/blend/9993cea4b1df4396be8ceb93fbd7f823

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address raised the issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Comment: didn't Christopher answer here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260601/object-has-no-materials-on-it-but-still-displays-there-to-be-a-material

Answer (score 1):

**Select the can, and choose from the material drop-down menu the "can" material. That'll add the material to the can, so you can edit the material further.** Why the mesh had a hidden material in the first place is a bug of some kind.